# Why does my ethernet crash when downloading at high speeds?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

First off I'm running Windows 10 64-bit on the latest update, I use an ethernet card* but this happens with my onboard** ethernet port too.

**The problem:**

When downloading at high speeds my network crashes and stays down until I disconnect and reconnect my ethernet cable. This happens whether I use my built-in ethernet port, or an ethernet card I bought specifically because of this issue. It happened in Windows 8.1, and happens regardless of router/modem I'm conencted to - as long as the download speed is over 15mB/sec or so for a random amount of time (Usually 30-60 seconds or more).

Latest crash:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67DC0D66-3695-47C0-9642-33F76F7BD7AD}" /> 
  <EventID>22</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>1015</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-06-03T16:19:19.259454600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>32536</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="NicNameLen">46</Data> 
  <Data Name="NicName">/DEVICE/{1B10BC46-E79C-4395-B695-7C0ED2B4DC1F}</Data> 
  <Data Name="NicFNameLen">34</Data> 
  <Data Name="NicFName">Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

---

> *TP-Link 10/100/1000Mbps Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express, PCIE Network Adapter / Network Card / Ethernet Card for PC, Win10 supported (TG-3468)
>
> **MSI Gaming Z97 GAMING 5 LGA 1150 Intel Z97 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard

Comment: Any relevant events logged in the System event log? Can you ping other devices after the crash?

Comment: "Media disconnected on NIC /DEVICE/{1B10BC46-E79C-4395-B695-7C0ED2B4DC1F} (Friendly Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller)." and "NIC /DEVICE/{1B10BC46-E79C-4395-B695-7C0ED2B4DC1F} (Friendly Name: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller) is no longer operational.". I can't ping other devices on the network, and like I said - router doesn't matter, I've tested it with multiple routers and ethernet cables.

Comment: Get rid of the RealTek card and try an Intel network adapter.  Your local computer recycler or used computer shop probably has them for about $5.

Comment: Very likely a driver bug, so indeed the simplest solution is probably to get another network adapter.

Comment: Could you give the entire text of the events from the Event Viewer? You could add it to your post. Even screenshots of Event Viewer will help.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: "TP-Link" and "D-link" - has about the same "value", avoid if you can. Realtek things has worked well for me despite the cheap price (at <=1Gb). Please also note: "mB" is not valid for transmission speed, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix .

Comment: The error happens on a Hyper-V virtual adapter. Are you inside a virtual machine? Or do you have a Hyper-V virtual machine running?

Comment: No it's not running in a virtual machine, and no virtual machines are running... Which is weird

Comment: Try to uninstall the Hyper-V feature and see if this makes a difference. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: So, assuming you have the [newest driver](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tg-3468/v3/#Driver) installed, have you tried moving the card to a different PCIe slot? I've seen bad PCIe slots "behave correctly" until the device comes "under load" Then they crash or do strange things.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall Hyper-V?

Comment: Given up on the bounty @Jon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I didn't read all of the current answers but they seem to be saying relatively the same thing, and it might be a much simpler issue. I recommend trying this:

> 1. Go to Device Manager
> 2. Expand Network adapters
> 3. Right-click the offending adapter
> 4. Select Properties
> 5. Go to the Power Management tab
> 6. Uncheck the box next to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

If that does not solve your problem, you may also:

> 7. Go to the Advanced tab
> 8. Select the Speed & Duplex property
> 9. Change the Value from "Auto Negotiation" to "100 Mbps Half Duplex"
> 10. Click OK

See if that fixes it for you; it worked for me when my ISP made a change to my internet speed and I would disconnect from games consistently.

Comment: "I didnt read everything but I think I got a better solution". Great philosophy xD

Comment: "This sounds like a driver bug. It was the best of times, it was the worst of times..." T_T

Comment: Yeah, the difference is that my statement is based on a large experience with those toys people call Windows OS, and if I claim it is a driver bug it is because the OP said that he upgraded from windows8, and one of the most common issues when upgrading was an incorrect drivers update, which usually leds to strange bugs on "random" components. I thought the OP did not need to know all this. Your answer was just lazy xD, thats why I laughed, however,I think I did it in a polite enough way, taking into consideration you're doing your best to help others :D.Have a nice day and ty for contributing

Comment: If you don't understand that my comment responding to yours was just as polite and appropriate as yours was, I can't really help you. While your answer is incredibly helpful, it's also incredibly verbose - which is why I only skimmed it and prefaced my answer with a "I didn't read all of the current answers" - in case I missed some part where you addressed network adapter properties. My answer isn't lazy, it's succinct - if you spent as much time editing down your answer as you have getting offended and being disingenuously polite/playful in the comments, it would be more palatable for users.

Comment: If you can't see why your answer looks lazy, I can't help you either. Btw, I'd try using smoke signals, if you're going to cut down your adapter's capabilities, why not going to the extreme?. Anyway, english is not my mom language, so maybe I sound angry or unpolite, sorry if thats the case, i really had fun reading your comment addressing mine, I'm not mnuch of a resuming guy

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a driver bug.

Although a clean W10 install is properly the best choice for you, specially if you updated from Windows 8.1, there are other solutions. Upgraded Windows 8 -> 10 are a living driver hell, trust me, I had to face a lot of them in the past, and it is not a joy. My experience tells that, whenever it is possible, you should perform a clean and proper Windows 10 install. The alternative is being lucky with a full driver reinstall or facing some hours of googling for specifics of your hardware to make it work properly

The easiest alternative is to download the lastest driver from the manufacturer ([this is the link](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tg-3468/#Driver) to the TP-link page, select the proper version of your NIC (V1, V2 or V3), [this one](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-GAMING-5#down-driver&Win10%2064) is for your motherboard), remove EVERY network driver used in your system preferably with a cleaner of your choice, and THEN reboot (twice is SOMETIMES, I won't get into details about this, but in some rare scenarios not everything will be properly detected after first reboot) and install the latest drivers.

Downloading before uninstalling is important, for obvious reasons ;)

I usually preffer Intel over Realtek, there's not much price difference between them and Intel ones tend to give less driver problems and higher quality, although this can be a matter of discussion, so stick to your favorite.

I just checked your [motherboard spec's](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/Z97-GAMING-5.html) and they claim to temper with the NIC in order to give priority to game packets:

> The Killer™ E2200 Intelligent Networking Platform is built for maximum networking performance for online games and high-quality streaming media. Featuring Advanced Stream Detect™, Killer E2200 automatically detects and accelerates game traffic ahead of other network traffic for smoother, stutter-free in-game performance and the competitive edge. With this exclusive, automatic traffic prioritization, games and real-time chat get priority over low-level system chatter, giving you the lowest latency for game data on the most controllable network hardware available.

Maybe there's some problem with your mother board software which is not properly configured with your network card. Uninstall ALL MSI software and download and install just what you need/use. When you select a network driver package, pick the small one, not the 100+MB, pick the "only driver" version. Usually you can find the missing drivers in stand-alone packages or as options in their installers, avoiding their buggy software. [This is the download link](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-GAMING-5#down-driver&Win10%2064) for your mobo's drivers for Windows 10 x64. As you're experiencing network issues, I recommend you to download the "driver only" version of the network driver ([link to the w10 x64 version of the driver](http://download.msi.com/dvr_exe/Killer_network_w10_inf.zip)).

As a rule of thumb, those features usually are sellbaits which are poorly implemented and give more problems that what they solve. My strategy is to disable allways (I don't really use desktop mobos anymore, I just get server boards into big boxes with proper cooling and I'm much happier now, even for gaming, with a proper graphics card). Maybe I'm just too old for that, and maybe this is just a coincidence, but I rarely suffer problems like those on my machines or on machines installed by me xD.

Again, pardon me for being repetitive, but my first suggestion prevails over all those: Perform a clean windows 10 install with the LATEST version in the DVD, so you dont have to upgrade to a newer windows 10 version. Everything will work much more smoothy

[MS Windows 10 official download link](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10)

You could also try removing Hyper-V as someone says, but it rathers seems ot be a sympthom, not the cause:

```
Dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Comment: The driver causing the problem is that of the virtual adapter of Hyper-V, and it is not being used at all. Also, advising the reinstall of Windows is rather irresponsible.

Comment: what is irresponsable is to have an upgraded windows 8 to 10. It will never work properly, been dealing with it for years.

Comment: Besides, W10 is a big toy. Even with hard programing environments, you can have it completly set up and running with the basics (8-10 IDES plus conda, jdk and so on) in a couple days. If you want to pretend a toy is a working tool, it is okey, but you'll have to clean it from time to time :p

Comment: @harrymc besides, Hyper-V falling down, as you suggest as the solution, seems to be more a sympthom than the root cause of the problem. Something he has never touch suddenly fails affecting other parts of the system? Okey, it is Windows, so every possible shit that can go wrong will, but anyway, its not a normla behaviour. If I had to put my bucks on it, I'd go for the driver issue. Anyway, removing Hyper-V is easy, so I provided the guy a command to do so, just in case you're right.

Comment: And please, tell me what is irrepsonsible in reinstalling a wrongly performed installation?

Comment: Just to clarify - I didn't go from Win8->Win10 using the upgrader, I reinstalled completely on a new SSD.

Answer (score 0):

The error arrives on a Virtual Switch of Hyper-V,
and you say that you are not using Hyper-V.

In that case, the simplest solution would be to uninstall Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing this issue as well after I attempted to manually overclock my memory. Downloads would keep cancelling whenever download speeds got "too fast." After I reverted my memory overclock, the downloads went smoothly again, without fail.

For the ordinary folk, run memory tests to make sure that your RAM is stable and not faulty. Consider raising the RAM voltage or replacing the RAM if memory tests do detect issues.